# Unable to get id of record with json data (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am working in laravel 5.3 i have store json form data in a field and know i want to retrieve that data to show in view to edit.i am getting data but i also want id of that record.

**my laravel controller edit function**

```
$data = Students::findOrFail($id);
 $student_data = DB::table('students')->select('id','json_record')->first();
 $test = json_decode($notification_smtp->json_record);

 print_r($test);
            die;
```

in output i get only the json_record not the id how can i get this id also 
Please Help to fix it
if i try on 2nd line of my code

```
echo $data->id;
        die;
```

It returns me actual id but i want to get it with json_record .

```
stdClass Object ( [name] => Test [list_group] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [student_lists] => Array ( [0] => 22 [1] => 11 [2] => 21 ) [users] => all)
```

Comment: use  $test = json_decode($notification_smtp->json_record, true);

Comment: its just removed std class from start

Comment: have you tried $notification_smtp->id

Comment: it have id of 1st element mean id 1 but requirement is that it should be selected one here as 9

Comment: Could you cleanup your code? $data variable is not used, the query result is saved to $student_data that you don't use, but later you make use of undefined $notification_smtp variable

Answer (score 0):

The **id** is stored in separate column, not in the encoded JSON data.

You can access it with **$notification_smtp->id**.

If you want to add it to the decoded data, do the following:

```
$test = json_decode($notification_smtp->json_record, true);
$test['id'] = $id;

print_r($test);
```

Comment: What does print_r($notification_smtp); give you?

Comment: i have get id but its the id of ist record i want to get it for selected record which i want to edit mean in this can its 1 but i am on id 9 .please help for this

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Where should the value 9 come from if it's not the ID of the record?

Comment: $data = Students::findOrFail($id); i want this $id.... not the id for ist record of my table...
I am working on edit so the id should be for ist record not for ist record of my db field

Comment: i have added this code it have id in it but i am getting error as 
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\application-laravel\resources\views\student\create.blade.php)

Comment: I don't see your create.blade.php but I guess the reason is that $test is an array, not an object. Try accessing its content by using array syntax in your blade template